# Fly Traveling Over Surface of a Plane

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm struggling with starting a problem in my Calc 3 class, at least with just starting it.

The temperature on a plane at location $(x, y)$ equals $f(x, y) = x^2 - y + 10$, and the bug is moving on the plane. At a certain time $t = t_0$, the bug is at $(1, 3)$ and moving with a velocity of $\langle 2, 1 \rangle$. What is the rate of change of temperature experienced by the bug? [Hint: Use the chain rule.]

In other versions of this question I've seen online, the student is given an $r(t)$ function to plug in for chain rule, not a velocity function. My professor also rushed through chain rule rather rapidly, so I'm uncertain of the basic premise of that.

Thanks!

Comment: the total derivative $\frac {df}{dt} = \frac {\partial f}{\partial x}\frac {dx}{dt} + \frac {\partial f}{\partial y}\frac {dy}{dt}$

Answer (score 1):

Because it moves in a straight line, the position $r(t)=(1,3)+t(2,1)$